# Call a REST API that returns a JSON from react-app

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a url for a REST API, like `'https://someurl/test'` that responds with a JSON and I need to import that data to my React application(s).

I wanted to call that endpoint from a react based SPA.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`import` only works for local files (unless there's a babel/webpack plugin I'm unaware of).

If the file is static, you can download it and put it somewhere in your projects files and then import it.

If the file changes frequently then you should make a HTTP fetch (for example using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md)) to request the file as it's needed. The exact specifics of how to do this will depend on your use-case (eg if this is for client or for SSR).

Answer (score -2):

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>console.log(data));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)